# Artemis STOMP: address or queue expiry

Tags: java, stomp, activemq-artemis

Is it possible to set expiration for queues or addresses if we use [durable subscriptions](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/stomp.html#durable-subscriptions) in STOMP?

Artemis automatically deletes auto-created queues by default, but "durable" subscription queues remain forever. I've tried setting the `expiry-delay` `address-setting` which will delete the messages if no `expiry-address` is defined. However, Artemis keeps the subscription queues anyway which causes the server to run out of memory. I have to delete container in Docker every 3 days. As you can imagine, this is not good at all.

Unfortunately, it often happens when the client closes the browser without unsubscribing.

Here is the relevant portion of `broker.xml`:

```xml
<address-setting match="#">
    <expiry-delay>3600000</expiry-delay> <!-- 1 hours -->
    <default-address-routing-type>MULTICAST</default-address-routing-type>

    <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
    <!--<expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>-->
    <redelivery-delay>15000</redelivery-delay>
    <max-delivery-attempts>10</max-delivery-attempts>

    <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
    <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
    <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
    <auto-delete-addresses>true</auto-delete-addresses>

    <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
    <auto-delete-queues>true</auto-delete-queues>

    <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
    <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
    <auto-delete-jms-queues>true</auto-delete-jms-queues>
    <auto-delete-jms-topics>true</auto-delete-jms-topics>
</address-setting>
```

Answer (score 0):

The queues used for STOMP durable subscriptions are not considered to be *auto*-created since the client is specifically asking for a durable subscription. The whole point of having a durable subscription is so that it will retain messages which are sent while the client is not connected. If the client disconnects without unsubscribing the assumption is that it will eventually reconnect and consume the messages in its durable subscription.

Of course, some clients won't do that which is the problem you're facing. You might consider if durable subscriptions are really what you want. Non-durable subscriptions won't suffer from this problem, of course.

However, if you *must* use durable subscriptions then you should set `auto-delete-created-queues` to `true` and you can tune the `auto-delete-queues-message-count` and `auto-delete-queues-delay` to fit your needs, e.g.:

```xml
<address-setting match="yourAddress">
    <auto-delete-created-queues>true</auto-delete-created-queues>
    <auto-delete-queues-message-count>-1</auto-delete-queues-message-count>
    <auto-delete-queues-delay>3600000</auto-delete-queues-delay>
</address-setting>
```

This combination of settings will ensure that any durable subscription queue on the address `yourAddress` is deleted 1 hour after the last consumer disconnects no matter how many messages it contains.

Also, be aware the these settings are deprecated so you shouldn't use them:

```xml
<auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
<auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
<auto-delete-jms-queues>true</auto-delete-jms-queues>
<auto-delete-jms-topics>true</auto-delete-jms-topics>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. We really need "durable subscriptions", so Artemis was installed instead of the default one in Spring Framefork.

However, this does not solve the problem of removing the address if the clients have not unsubscribed. I understand the essence of a long-term subscription, but it would be logical to destroy unnecessary addresses upon expiration, at will, rather than store them forever, because in our case, it only hurts.

Comment: I provided a solution for removing the queue for the durable subscription. Assuming that the corresponding address is auto-created then it will be auto-deleted when there are no more queues bound to it. Are you seeing different behavior (i.e. lingering addresses with no queues bound)?

Comment: The problem is that until the user unsubscribes, the queue will exist, and with it the address. Therefore, I see a constant accumulation of such addresses with dead unnecessary queues.

Comment: I don't understand. Did you apply the solution that I outlined in my answer? It should remove the subscription queue(s) as explained.

Comment: Did everything exactly, but it didn't work as I expected. After updating to 2.15.0 with a slightly different configuration, it worked as expected. Thanks again for your help

Comment: I assumed you were using the latest version (i.e. 2.15.0) since you didn't specify. There was a typo in my XML which I've fixed. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to 2.15.0, it works as expected.

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a:
> Invalid content was found starting with element 'auto-delete-delay'.

My current configuration:

```
<expiry-delay>3600000</expiry-delay> <!-- 1 hours -->
<auto-delete-created-queues>true</auto-delete-created-queues>
<auto-delete-queues-delay>3600000</auto-delete-queues-delay> <!-- 1 hours -->
```

This will delete queues after a specified time that have no messages and have not been unsubscribed from properly

Comment: To be clear, the broker has no idea that the durable subscriber did not unsubscribe "properly." These settings will delete *any* queue that fits the configuration. This configuration still runs the risk of message pile-up because it requires the queue to have 0 messages (unlike in my answer).

Comment: Messages are supposed to be deleted using expiry-delay and this works great, but I keep testing

Comment: Messages *will* be deleted, but each message has to wait for the `expiry-delay` to elapse. Consider the scenario where message `A` arrives in a queue and receives an `expiry-delay` of 1 hour. Then after 59 minutes message `B` arrives in the queue and also receives an `expiry-delay` of 1 hour. Message `A` will be deleted 1 minute after message `B` arrives, but message `B` will stay in the queue for another 59 minutes. If this keeps happening the queue will never be deleted. In order for the message-count to reach 0 and the queue to be deleted *no new messages can arrive for 1 hour*.